# On IE input text is non-editable. It is implemented with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

On IE the **input[type="text"] is not editing** and also, **I am not getting scroll bar for the list by using overflow by setting height in IE**. In chrome it is working fine.
   Is there any hack code to make text box editable?.

**I want make the text box editable.**
**I also, want to get scroll bar for the vertical list items in IE**

**I searched in this stackoverflow. Not able to get proper solution**

If anyone can come up with the solution it would be great.

I am thanking you people in advance.

Comment: Can you please share your HTML code?

Comment: please check the classes or their respective values in IE as there is difference in the class name and compatibility in different browsers

Comment: Hi all,
Its happening for **ng-dropdown-multiselect**
HTML code.


`<div class="form-group">
                <label>Company</label>
                <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="vm.tenantUserSelectData" selected-model="vm.tenantUserSelectModel" extra-settings="vm.tenantUserSelectSettings" translation-texts="{'dynamicButtonTextSuffix': ''}" events="vm.tenantUserSelectEvents" disabled="vm.tenantUserSelectEnable" class="user-icon filter-icon"  ng-class="{selected: vm.tenantUserSelectModel.length}"></div>
              </div>`